# Getting MissingMethodInvocationException while testing with servlet and session

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets, mockito

I'm trying to test my servlet to see if it calls my `DAOService` with some passed parameters from the session but running into this problem

The log:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
at Servlet.SupplierServletTest.supplierServlet_StandardTest(SupplierServletTest.java:32)
```

The code

```
SupplierServlet supplierServlet = new SupplierServlet();
MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/SupplierServlet").buildRequest(new MockServletContext());
MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
MockHttpSession session = new MockHttpSession();

when(request.getSession()).thenReturn(session); //This is the line 32 that the log mentioned, I deleted the session part and the problem was the same for the following lines
when(request.getParameter("Name")).thenReturn("test"); 
when(request.getParameter("Address")).thenReturn("test");
when(request.getParameter("Phone")).thenReturn("1234");

supplierServlet.processRequest(request, response);
supplierDAO = mock(SupplierDAO.class);
verify(supplierDAO).newSupplier(new Supplier("test", "test", "1234"));
```

Any tip is appreciated

Comment: MockHttpServletRequest isn't a Mockito recognised mock.

Comment: I was using that mock from Spring test as someone suggested in my previous question. I'm trying to do things in Mockito's way right now to see if there's any improvement, but the initiation so far is a pain

Comment: just use `addParameter()`[javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html#addParameter-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) (exclusive!)OR use Mockio...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for initialising `MockHttpServletRequest`, you should use the Spring provided builder. Since it is a class offered by the Spring framework (and is not a Mockito mock), using Mockito to mock its methods will result in an error.

```java
MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
MockHttpSession session = new MockHttpSession();
MockHttpServletRequest request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/SupplierServlet")
    .session(session)
    .param("Name", "test")
    .param("Address", "test")
    .param("Phone", "1234")
    .buildRequest(new MockServletContext());

supplierServlet.processRequest(request, response);
supplierDAO = mock(SupplierDAO.class);
verify(supplierDAO).newSupplier(new Supplier("test", "test", "1234"));
```

Moreover, your `supplierDAO` mock is useless. After mocking an object, you need to inject it into the code under test. It is usually done by passing the mock as a function parameter. Whereas in your test, you're trying to verify calls on a mock that was never used.

Comment: Thank you, the ```supplierDAO``` part is to verify whether if it's called since it should be called if the servlet works as intended in the test

Comment: @LongDoan Yes, but the `SupplierDAO` (mock) instance in your test code is independent of the `SupplierDAO` instance in your servlet. You cannot verify calls on a (mocked) instance unless your servlet also uses the same instance.

Comment: I see, thank you